# Printing a dictionary with str in Python

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary on python:

```
dic = {1:'Ááa',2:'lol'}
```

if I printing it appears

```
print dic
{1: '\xc3\x81\xc3\xa1a', 2: 'lol'}
```

How can I obtain the following ouput  ?

```
print dic
{1: 'Ááa', 2: 'lol'}
```

Comment: Works in Python3! Time to upgrade

Comment: Works in my Python-2.7. Also where on earth is `'hola'` coming from.

Comment: And how did `hola` become `lol`?

Comment: It would not work in python2 as you are seeing the repr output

Comment: Yea @BhargavRao , in Python 3.4.2  it works , that's ok for me (and I change 'lol' now)

Comment: why do you want the output like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that as the strings within data structure like dictionary or list printed by [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method of string not [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). for more info read [What is the difference between **str** and **repr** in Python](http://www.pythoncentral.io/what-is-the-difference-between-__str__-and-__repr__-in-python/)

> [repr(object)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr)
>
> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object.

As an alternative you can convert the items to string and print them :

```
>>> print '{'+','.join([':'.join(map(str,k)) for k in dic.items()])+'}'
{1:Ááa,2:lol}
```

Comment: If you have a nested dict or list as a value etc.. the alternative won't work

Comment: You can use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension by dropping those square brackets. That'll saves time and memory by avoiding building a `list` that will be iterated over once and then discarded.

Comment: @BlacklightShining yeah, it's a better ideal i always forget that!

Comment: @BlacklightShining, using a generator expression with join is actually less efficient.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Really? Why?

Comment: @BlacklightShining, because python has to do two passes over the data when using join so using a generator means it has to build a list first.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If `str.join()` builds a list out of the iterable it is passed, then it should make no difference. I would still use a genexpr, for habit and practice if nothing else.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks do you have any reference that explain more?

Comment: @BlacklightShining, how do you do two passes over a generator? It only builds a list when you don't pass it one

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind getting just the strings, without the enclosing quotes, you could iterate over the `dict` and print out each key-value pair yourself.

```
from __future__ import print_function

for key, value in dict_.iteritems():
    print(key, value, sep=': ', end=',\n')
```

If you're just going to print once, I would do this rather than building a string. If you want to do other things, or print them more than once, use [Kasra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29590993/1561811).

This does get confusing if the keys or values have colons, commas, or newlines in them, and the output won't be a valid Python literal, but it's the simplest way short of upgrading to Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do what you want.  I created a class to represent the data the way you wanted it.  However you should note that a dictionary data type is no longer being returned. This is just a quick way to represent the data.  The first line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` globally specifies the encoding type. So if you just want to be able to print your dictionary this will work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class print_dict(object):

    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.mydict = dictionary

    def __str__(self):
        represented_dict = []
        for k, v in self.mydict.items():
             represented_dict.append("{0}: {1}".format(k, v))
        return "{" + ", ".join(represented_dict) + "}"





dic = {1: 'Ááa', 2: 'lol'}
print print_dict(dic)
```

Comment: As with [Kasara's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29590993/1561811), consider using a generator expression instead of building a list and passing it to `str.join()`.

Comment: That's a good modification to add.  When i get a chance i'll reimplement.

Comment: Or maybe not. [Padraic has pointed out to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590948/printing-a-dictionary-with-str-in-python/29591238#comment47329651_29590993) that [passing `str.join()` a listcomp is actually more efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/2141635). I got similar results with Python 3 on my system, too.

Comment: lol oh okay, then i'll leave as is, the OP can do the research if they want to return a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in python 3.

This is how it looks like when executed in python shell.

```
>>> dic={1: 'Ááa',2: 'lol'}
>>> print(dic)
{1: 'Ááa', 2: 'lol'}
```